# Internal test using play console, how do I unpublish app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have uploaded my apk and added testers by gmail.

It states I have to publish the app to use the opt in link.

I am testing my app - I do not want to publish it.

How can I create an internal test without publishing my app?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: The docs are not clear. Why would you have to publish an app to test it - it doesnt make sense